# yield in ERB without rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

How can I use *yield* for template inheritance in erb?  I want to use erb in a plain ruby CGI script and want to use a base template and subtemplate like it Rails with the application template does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can - Rails provides that infrastructure as part of actionpack.

What you may be able to do is take actionpack and add it into your script.

Alternatively you could roll a lightweight templating system yourself.

Alternatively alternatively use Rails or Merb or Sinatra.

Comment: Despite the down-votes, the layouts and template inheritance is part of Rails, not ERB itself.

Answer (score 38):

```
def a
  ERB.new('<%= yield %>').result(binding)
end
a{123}
#=> "123"
```

It's important that the call to `Kernel#binding` be inside a method, that way the context includes the block (`ERB#result` won't take a block).

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work. How does ERB know that it should be rendering a in the yield?

Answer (score 5):

Check out Tilt (http://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/).  It's the gem that handles templating in Sinatra and it provides ERB yields along with many other nice features.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Tilt but if you don't want to add an extra dependency, here's a better example on how you can yield in erb:

```
require "erb"

class Controller
  TEMPLATE = ERB.new("Hello <%= @someone %>\n\n<%= yield %>")

  def initialize(someone)
    @someone = someone
  end

  def render
    TEMPLATE.result(self.get_binding { yield })
  end

  def get_binding
    binding
  end
end

puts Controller.new("World").render { "I'm Jack" }
# =>
Hello World

I'm Jack
```

I found the answer [here](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/yielding-in-erb-templates/).

Answer (score 1):

app.rb

```
require 'erb'

class Template
    def render(template_name="base")
        ERB.new(File.read("#{template_name}.erb")).result(binding)
    end
end

result = Template.new.render do
    ERB.new(File.read("index.erb")).result
end

puts result
```

base.erb

```
<main>
    <%= render "footer" %>
    <%=yield %>
</main>
```

index.erb

```
<h1>Index Page</h1>
```

footer.erb

```
<h1>Footer here</h1>
```

output image:

[image]