# How to implement erb partials in a non rails app?

Tags: ruby, erb, partials

I want to do something like this:

```
require 'erb'
@var = 'test'
template = ERB.new File.new("template.erb").read
rendered = template.result(binding())
```

But how can I use partials in template.erb?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2467313/772874 You need `ActionView` for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps brute-force it?

```
header_partial = ERB.new(File.new("header_partial.erb").read).result(binding)
footer_partial = ERB.new(File.new("footer_partial.erb").read).result(binding)

template = ERB.new <<-EOF
  <%= header_partial %>
  Body content...
  <%= footer_partial %>
EOF
puts template.result(binding)
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I came up with as well ;)

Comment: Is there some gem which could help with that?

Comment: This is an awesome answer and helped save me a ton of time. One quick note on this: if your partial needs to access a variable that changes (say, an index value that increments once per loop), you'll need to regenerate the partial on each loop.

Answer (score 2):

Was trying to find out the same thing and didn't find much that was satisfying other than using the [Tilt gem](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt), which wraps ERB and other templating systems and supports passing blocks (aka, the results of a separate render call) which may be a little nicer.

Seen on:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-the-tilt-gem--net-20027

**layout.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title><%= title %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your ruby call

```
template = Tilt::ERBTemplate.new("layout.erb")

File.open "other_template.html" do |file|
    file.write template.render(context) {
        Tilt::ERBTemplate.new("other_template.erb").render
    }
end
```

It will apply the results of the `other_template` into the `yield` body.