# Is it possible to evaluate a yield statement in an html.erb template using the ERB library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

The ERB library I refer to is [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html).

```
require 'ERB'
simple_template = "Statement: <%= yield %>."
renderer = ERB.new(simple_template)
```

I want to be able to pass in a block to be used in the `yield` statement in `simple_template`. Is there some way to do this with the ERB library?

The following does not work:

```
renderer.result { "I am yielded" }  # LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
```

Neither does:

```
prc = Proc.new { "I am yielded" }
renderer.result(prc) # TypeError: wrong argument type proc (expected binding)
```

Is there a better way to do this than using ERB library?

This question seems to refer to what happens in a Rails application in application.html.erb.

Update:
Here are question duplicates I found:
[yield in ERB without rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460839/yield-in-erb-without-rails?rq=1)

Comment: Are you just trying to execute logic and keep it out of your view file?

Comment: I'm trying to actually implement my own (much more basic) version of the Rails web framework, and that involves rendering a view formed by a basic application.html.erb type view and another view that gets inserted in the yield statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the block you want to context wherein you create the [`Binding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Binding.html) that you'll use with the template:

```
require 'erb'


def render(name)
  TEMPLATE.result(binding)
end

render('evianpring') { 'blocks' }
# => "evianpring yields to the power of blocks!"
```

Let's dive into why this works. From the binding docs:

> Objects of class Binding encapsulate the execution context at some
>   particular place in the code and retain this context for future use.
>   The variables, methods, value of self, and possibly an iterator block
>   that can be accessed in this context are all retained.

So what's available in execution context of the binding were creating here?

```
def render(name)
  TEMPLATE.result(binding)
end
```

- Any variables local to `#render()` like `name`
- Any globals like `TEMPLATE`
- Any block we pass to `#render()`

Hence if we want to use yield will need to pass a block to `#render()`

Comment: The documentation on binding doesn't say much about using blocks with it (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html). Why does this not work (assuming you've defined variable name somewhere before): TEMPLATE.result(binding { "blocks" }). This generates a LocalJumpError: no block given (yield). Is this a binding thing or a Ruby thing that I am missing about putting a yield inside of a block?

Comment: I actually made a mistake. The yield call I had there originally is superfluous.